# I can not see a specific AP at `scan`(Expire BSS 1 due to no match in scan)

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant, wlan, wpa-cli

I am using `wpa_supplicant` and `wpa_cli`.
I have two "A2008-2.4G" APs.
These two APs created two APs with the same name to use WiFi Roaming.
At one moment, however, one of the two APs is not output to the scan_result command.

After debugging(wpa_supplicant), I was able to find the following message.

> wlan0: Event 5 received on interface wlan0
>   Wireless event: cmd=0x8b19 len=8
>   wlan0: Event 3 received on interface wlan0
>   Scan results did not fit - trying larger buffer (8192 bytes)
>   Received 6580 bytes of scan results (22 BSSes)
>   wlan0: BSS: Start scan result update 25
>   wlan0: BSS: `Expire BSS 1 dut to no match in scan`
>   wlan0: BSS: `Remove id 1 BSSID 90:9f:33:62:9b:6e SSID "A2008-2.4G"`
>   CTRL_IFACE monitor send - hexdump(len=20): 2f 74 6d 70 2f 77 70 61 5f 63 74 72 6c 5f 3f 36 35 2d 32 00

One of the two A2008-2.4G was removed under certain conditions.
In my case, why is this particular AP being removed at scan time?
And how should I solve this phenomenon?

Comment: 1)  Are you detecting your network from other devices in the same location?  2)  Does it find any other networks on this computer?

Comment: 1)Yes. I have detected two "A2008-2.4G" in my WiFi Analyzer App on my Android phone.
2)Yes. It is possible to scan other networks except that one "A2008-2.4G" is deleted.

Comment: First step is to find out if the problem is in wpasupplicant or the kernel. What does `iw wlan0 scan` show? Is it working correctly?